# Assign ArrayList<String> to File[] in java

Tags: java, file, arraylist

How to assign `ArrayList` of `String` to `File[]` in java. I have tried as shown below

```
ArrayList<String> fileList;

File[] file;

for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
    file = new File (fileList.get(i));
}
```

But I am getting `file` cannot be converted to `File[]`. Please correct me.

Comment: do `file[i] = new File (fileList.get(i));` Also, do initialize the array first

Comment: `fileList.stream().map(File::new).toArray(File[]::new)`. Also, don't use the `File` API - it's awful. Use the new `Path` API...

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to initialize the array like

```
File[] file = new File[list.size()];
```

Now, you need to access the indexes of the array, like

```
for(int i = 0;i<fileList.size();i++) {
    file[i] = new File(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Hi, When I read from a folder like as shown below,  like as shown below File folder = new File("C:\\Test\\); i was able to get files properly. But same if i try by passing ArrayList<Strings> , where this ArrayList<String> contains file names ,i am getting issue during   in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(files[i])); Do you know possible reason for this?

Comment: @user2967784 That's a new question, and should be asked as a new question, and when you do so, don't just say 'getting issue'.